# Probably of at least one occurrence for very small probabilities

Tags: probability

I know how to calculate the odds of at least one event, but I can't do it for very small probabilities and I was wondering if there was a formula for approximating this or maybe you can point me to an online tool that can handle these numbers.

I'm trying to calculate chance of hash collision over many attempts.

```
Let p_bad = 1.75E-69, chance of hash collision
Let p_good = 1-p_bad, chance of no collision for 1 attempt
Let p_good_all = p_good^20000, chance of no collision for 20k attempts
Let p_at_least_one_bad = 1-g_good_all, chance of at least 1 collision among 20k attempts.
```

I believe that is the right probability logic, but I have no way of calculating the result with these numbers.
Is there another reformulation that makes this problem tractable or is there a tool that lets me calculate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small $p$, $1-(1-p)^n \approx np$.

You can see this from the Binomial Theorem:
$$1-(1-p)^n = 1 - \left(1 -np + \binom{n}{2}p^2 - \dots \pm p^n \right)$$
If $p$ is small then we can neglect all the terms involving $p^2$ or higher, with the result
$$1-(1-p)^n \approx 1 - (1 - np) = np$$

In your case, you have $p = 1.75 \times 10^{-69}$ and $n = 20,000$.

Situations like this are quite common in numerical calculation.  In this case in particular, if you try to compute $1-p$ you end up with $1$ due to the limits of floating point calculation.  The trick is to recognize this situation when it occurs and replace the exact computation with a suitable approximation.

Comment: I think the other answers are correct but your explanation made the most sense to me

Answer (score 0):

If $p=1.75\cdot10^{-69}$ then $\log(1-p) \approx -p$.  Therefore, $\log(1-p)^{20000}\approx -3.5\cdot10^{-64}$ and $(1-p)^{20000}\approx \exp(-3.5\cdot10^{-64})\approx 1-3.5\cdot10^{-64}$.

Comment: How do you get log(1−)≈−? Is that a special property?

Comment: From the power series for $\log(1-x)$.  Later on I used the power series for $e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

actually birthday paradox states that P(all_good) = $\frac{!start}{!stop}\frac{1}{start^{start-stop}}$ where start is number of all good values at beginning and stop is number of all good values at end of process  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

so algorithm is like this

```
res = 1.
for i in start..(stop+1):
    res = res * i / start
return res
```